# How to count all rows returned from a JPASubQuery query via QueryDSL?

Tags: jpa, querydsl

My subQuery returns a list of all serviceTypeIds and their respective counts in a table called 'billingData'.

I would like to perform a count(*) operation on the subQueryResult

```
JPASubQuery subQuery = new JPASubQuery();
subQuery.from(billingData);
subQuery.where(
        billingData.serviceTypeId.in(ServiceType.TYPE_ONE.getId(), ServiceType.TYPE_ONE_TWO.getId())
                .and(billingData.accountId.isNull())
                .and(billingData.price.isNotNull())
                .and(billingData.numberId.eq(numbers.id)));//join condition
subQuery.groupBy(billingData.serviceTypeId);
subQuery.having(billingData.count().goe(1));
```

My count attempt

```
            subQuery
            .list(billingData.serviceTypeId, billingData.serviceTypeId.count())
            .count().eq(2L);
```

fails with error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found ','
```

The error occurs when you don't specify what to count.

I would like to perform just a simple count(*), but failing to find a way how to extract the column name from the subquery as a count parameter.

Really stuck here :/

Comment: Doesn't look like the problem is in your count. Can you provide the whole query?

Answer (score 1):

The following count expressions work

```
subQuery.list(billingData.serviceTypeId).count().eq(2L);

subQuery.count().eq(2L);

subQuery.unique(billingData.serviceTypeId.count()).eq(2L);
```

count with multiple columns is not supported by JPQL